# If a company goes private, does it still count as a capital gain/loss?

Tags: united-states, taxes, stocks, capital-gain

This is related to "[What happens to public shareholders when a public stock goes private?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/17169/9090)" I am pretty sure the answer is yes, but:

If you own stock in a public company which is bought out, does it still count as a capital gain or loss? Is it essentially treated like you sold the stock at the price of the buy-out? Do you still get a 1099-B from your broker?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> does it still count as a capital gain or loss?

Yes.

> Is it essentially treated like you sold the stock at the price of the buy-out?

Yes.

> Do you still get a 1099-B from your broker?

Yes.

Comment: +1 for jumping on this softball and knocking it out of the park.

Comment: that bit about *sold the stock at the buy-out price*, does the private company essentially mail you a check equal to the value of your stocks? Or the broker is responsible for this transition? What's the mechanics here?

Comment: @jxramos The broker handles it. Just like dividend payments, for example.

Comment: The broker handles it according to their rules for *corporate actions*, which generally are somewhat different from their rules for dividend payments.  For example, there won't be any possibility of "dividend reinvestment" in case of a buy-out.