# When a public company (e.g. Twitter) goes private, when do shareholders receive funds?

Tags: united-states, settling-and-clearing, merger-and-acquisition

I was wondering what is the reasonable time frame when ordinary investors receive the money from a sale of a company that is acquired to become private. I see Twitter was acquired on Thursday (Oct 27, 2022), but no funds have been received.

I see a [news](https://www.washingtonpost.com/technology/2022/10/28/elon-musk-acquisition-twitter/) item that says

> Shareholders will receive $54.20 per share of stock when all the
> paperwork is filed

But it is not clear how many days to be exact ? Suppose an investor needs money for another trade or needs to withdraw funds, how can one plan for that?

Comment: I don't know specifically about twitter, but I held shares in a company that was taken private several years ago and it took about 3 months till all the funds were distributed.

Comment: @littleadv 3 months sounds too much twitter was quick

Comment: It may have been 3 months from the announcement

Comment: @littleadv  I was looking for the duration for which either the cash or stock is unavailable. So in Case of Twitter, I could have sold it on open Market till Thursday( Oct 27, 2022). Friday and Monday I neither have access to Fund or stocks.

Comment: https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/20636/

Comment: Wow, it's been a decade... In my case it was never publicly traded, so that's probably why I don't remember the distinction

Answer (score 4):

I believe this works exactly the same as selling your stock in a normal market transaction.

The sale of Twitter was closed on October 27th (Thursday), so you've sold your stock on that day. The funds will follow [T+2 settlement](https://www.investor.gov/introduction-investing/general-resources/news-alerts/alerts-bulletins/investor-bulletins/updated-10) and arrive 2 business days later, in this case Monday, October 31st.

Comment: yes and no. ** yes  ** as it happened in T+2 , but  ** NO ** because in regular sale a sale is entered on the day (i.e T ) actual sale happened and fund is received on T+2 . in case of this , there was no sale shown on Oct 27th.

Answer (score 2):

This was my first encounter with a company whose stock I was holding. For Twitter, I received Fund on Oct 31/2022. It was not visible on 10/31/2022, but was visible on November 01's morning.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question here. It's at best a comment verifying that a specific sale followed the rule applicable.

Comment: I think it's borderline an answer, it does explain how it worked for the example given in the question.