# I own ASPIRO shares (Jay Z's new company). Now that it is going private, what about my shares?

Tags: united-states, investing, shares, nasdaq, going-private

I bought shares from ASPIRO ASP.ST at $1.05/share. Now, the company is going from public back to private in a couple of days!

What does this mean for me as a public shareholder? And what can I do, because I want to keep my shares? On Tuesday the stock went from $1.05 to $11 in a couple of hours (938% ... crazy) and then dropped again to $1.13...

Comment: Thanks.. So they're going to offer me the same price ?

Comment: D'oh!  Should have cashed out! :(

Comment: @dg99 I'm glad I left a limit sell order for $10 on my account. Crazy that it hit.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer Mine was at $12. :( :(

Comment: Related: [What happens to public shareholders when a public stock goes private?](http://money.stackexchange.com/q/17169/3546)

Answer (score 2):

From the [press release](https://finance.yahoo.com/news/aspiro-statement-aspiro-independent-bid-072800001.html)

> Based on Aspiro's closing share price of SEK 0.66 as of 29 January
>   2015, the Offer values each Aspiro share at SEK 1.05 and the total
>   value of the Offer at approximately SEK 464 million.[3] The Offer
>   represents a premium of.....

It seems you will get cash. I can't explain the pop to 11. You don't have any option to keep the shares.